# Smooth scrolling displays the behind of the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

Smooth scrolling displays the behind of the menu.
I am trying to make smooth scrolling after click on about us but the issue is my about us content is displaying behind of the menu.

My menu is position is fixed. I set the `height:100px` to the menu.

Please check my code and assist me what is wrong with this code.

Thanks in advance

```js
$(function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 1000);
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
body{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
 section {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.menu_1{background-color: #f9f9f9;width: 100%;height: 100px;z-index: 12;position: fixed;top: 0;}
.wrapper{margin-top: 100px;}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Menu-->
<div class="menu_1">
 <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
<!--Redirect-->
<section id="test">
<h2>Test</h2>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
<section id="about">
<h2>About</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
<section>
<h2>Contact</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>


<section>
<h2>Contact</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: nothing wrong but normal behavior ... you placed the menu out of the flow and above all content

Comment: so adjust the offste and make somthing like `scrollTop: target.offset().top - 40`

Comment: In the menu, I set z-index:12 and in the section, I added z-index:10

Comment: and 12 is bigger than 10 :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Yes I know. I have to set menu fixed and z-index:12 so that whatever the content has in the section that will be scrolling from behind from the menu

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Why you added -40?

Comment: if you want the scroll to not hide the about title when scrolling. Not an exact value but an idea to show you that you can control the offset

Comment: Replace `scrollTop: target.offset().top` with `scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50`, because that's where you specify where you want your scroll to end so you need to stop scrolling sooner if you want your `About` to be visible.

Comment: @reiallenramos, the problem is a smooth scroll. Please check my snippet. You will get idea

Comment: you said that it's *behind* the menu which is not an issue because YOU make it behind the menu. What did you expect to happen ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, In my snippet, If you click on about then about content should display below of the background color but it's going behind the after the click.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, the target is going behind because my menu is fixed.